# Does awaiting a non-Promise have any detectable effect?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2017

One can `await` a non-Promise and [that's good so](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8310).

All these expressions are valid and cause no error:

```
await 5
await 'A'
await {}
await null
await undefined
```

Is there any **detectable effect** of awaiting a non-Promise? Is there any difference in behavior one should be aware of to avoid a potential error? Any performance differences?

Are the following two lines completely same or do they *theoretically* differ?:

```
var x = 5
var x = await 5
```

How? Any example to demonstrate the difference?

PS: According [TypeScript authors](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8310#issuecomment-214892918), there is a difference:

> `var x = await 5;` is not the same as `var x = 5;`; `var x = await 5;` will assign x 5 in the next tern, where as `var x = 5;` will evaluate immediately.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

`await` is not a no-op. If the awaited thing is not a promise, it is wrapped in a promise and that promise is awaited. Therefore `await` changes the execution order (but you should not rely on it nevertheless):

The following outputs 1, 2, 3:

```js
console.log(1);

(async function() {
  var x = await 5;
  console.log(3);
})();

console.log(2);
```

With the `await` removed it's 1, 3, 2:

```js
    console.log(1);

    (async function() {
      console.log(3);
    })();

    console.log(2);
```

Additionally `await` does not only work on `instanceof Promise`s but on every object with a `.then` method:

```
await { then(cb) { /* nowhere */ } };
console.log("will never happen");
```

> Is there any detectable effect of awaiting a non-Promise?

Sure, `.then` gets called if it exists on the awaited thing.

> Is there any difference in behavior one should be aware of to avoid a potential error?

Don't name a method "then" if you don't want it to be a Promise.

> Any performance differences?

Sure, if you await things you will always defer the continuation to a microtask. But as always: You won't probably notice it (as a human observing the outcome).

Comment: _"but you should not rely on it nevertheless"_  Why not?

Comment: @aBetterOliver example: you start two very short running actions and want to work with their result. You know that action 1 finsihes earlier than action 2, so you  store the result of 1 in a variable, and access that when 2 is done. Now someone somewhen changes the algorithm, so that 1 is slower than 2. Your code breaks and no one knows why. If you have to execute async tasks in a specific order, you should write that down explicitly.

Comment: @JonasWilms Your example does not relate to your statement. You stated that one should not rely on the fact that await changes the execution order. This is wrong, we rely on it all the time (i.e. when exploiting the atomicity of synchronous blocks). Your example is about **two** async tasks and one relying on the empirical (yet not guaranteed) execution time of the other, which is just a general observation of parallel programming: *You cannot rely on the order of incomparable transactions in the precedence graph*

Comment: I disagree that the first example parallels (pardon the pun) the OP's example. To do so you'd have to await the console log, `await console.log(3);`, in which case there is no *observable* difference in *behavior*.

Answer (score 34):

Completely agreed with Jonas's statements. One thing that was not answered in his question was **Are the following two lines completely same or do they theoretically differ?:**

following two lines are not completely same, they're theoretically different.

1. var x = 5
2. var x = await 5

execution time in my console for 1st and 2nd statement is **0.008056640625ms** and **0.055908203125ms** respectively.
**async/await, setTimeOut etc are APIs provided by Run time in which JavaScript Run time is running.**
Putting await on a non-promise will be executed in `event-loop`. Line 1 will be executed right after reaching the `stack` but the line 2 will take few time(milliseconds) as it will 1st go to the `stack` and then to the `task queue` after skipping webAPI waiting section because there's no promise to be resolved & finally after that control will be given to `stack` again for execution.

Comment: I think this question was already answered with the example code snippet. Thank you anyway!

Comment: actually the last part of the question was missing though i.e **Are the following two lines completely same or do they theoretically differ?**.

Comment: The example code from @JonasWilms showed the difference very clearly...

Comment: great. assume it an other explanation then :)

Comment: This is an important distinction, because this behavior was "fixing" a bug for us implemented by a junior engineer that didn't realize the function they were `await`ing wasn't a promise and thus shouldn't be doing anything. "But it fixes the bug!" (a race condition bug that was "solved" by putting the non-promisified function onto the event loop... *after* other events) they had said. Little did we know none of us knew about this behavior of `await`....

Comment: But will it be synchronous. Can I be guaranteed that, in your example, a line 3. will never get executed before line 2. is complete?

Answer (score 0):

The awaited code gets wrapped in a promise if the thing awaited does not have a `then` property. Therefore, though there is a difference in performance (it takes longer), there is no *observable* difference in *behavior* unless what you await has a `then` property -- in which case behavior might be unpredictable if the thing awaited is not actually a promise which will complete.