# No typescript warning when awaiting non Promise function

Tags: typescript

Consider function below, it doesn't return promise, yet typescript doesn't warn about unnecessary use of await here. Is there a way to enforce this?

[image]

Comment: Awaiting a non-promise does have an effect, check out [my old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55262996/does-awaiting-a-non-promise-have-any-detectable-effect).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [by design](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8310#issuecomment-224774863), so don’t expect Typescript to be raising the error you’re looking for any time soon.

However, [TSLint can provide a warning or error for this case](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/await-promise/).