# Interface and implementation for an optionally async return method

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm wondering what the optimal way to go when you've got an interface method, whose implementations may return sync value in one implementation and async value in another.

Example:

```
export interface CacheType {
  get<T>(key: string): any
}
```

then we've got a sync implementation

```
export class LocalSyncCache implements CacheType {
  public get(key: string): T | undefined {
    return 'some_value_from_a_sync_storage'
  }
}
```

and async one

```
export class RemoteAsyncCache implements CacheType {
  public async get(key: string): Promise<T | undefined> {
    return await async_request('https://aws.amazon.com/get')
  }
}
```

What would be the correct return value for the method interface?

Assume everything async and just always await?

```
export interface CacheType {
  get(key: string): Promise<T | undefined>
}

export class LocalSyncCache implements CacheType {
  public async get(key: string): Promise<T | undefined> {
    return 'some_value_from_a_sync_storage'
  }
}

const localSyncCache = new LocalSyncCache()
const remoteAsyncCache= new RemoteAsyncCache()

await localSyncCache.get('foo')
await remoteAsyncCache.get('foo')
```

It works. Doesn't throw any errors. And I've seen it implemented in some popular codebases.
OK, but what about the fact that `await` on sync methods still changes the execution flow?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55263084/255408

Or just use type union and narrow down the types in implementations?

```
export interface CacheType {
  get(key: string): Promise<T | undefined> | T | undefined
}

export class LocalSyncCache implements CacheType {
  public get(key: string): T | undefined {
    return 'some_value_from_a_sync_storage'
  }
}

export class RemoteAsyncCache implements CacheType {
  public async get(key: string): Promise<T | undefined> {
    return await async_request('https://aws.amazon.com/get')
  }
}

const localSyncCache = new LocalSyncCache()
const remoteAsyncCache= new RemoteAsyncCache()

localSyncCache.get('foo')
await remoteAsyncCache.get('foo')
```

Comment: Will promises help in this case?

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan async/await are basically promises, not exactly sure what you mean

Comment: I thought if we could create a new promise out of that get() then promise.then(data => {}) would gave us the final data be it the first implementation without async or the latter with async call.

Comment: But then it will be the same issue of resolving the data... 

Comment: I would just make it async. Keeping the code simple and clean probably outweighs the performance impact (if any) in case of calling await on a sync function

Comment: "Or just use type union and narrow down the types in implementations?" gets my vote.