# is it necessary to await the result of every async function?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I've defined the following JavaScript function

```js
async isDataValid (externalValidation = true) {
    const isValid = (await this.v$.$validate()) && externalValidation
    // other stuff not relevant to my question happens here
    return isValid
}
```

AFAIK, I need to define this as an `async` function in order to await the result of `this.v$.$validate()`.

Because `isDataValid` is itself `async`, I thought I need to use `await` whenever I call it, but when I did the following:

```
const result = await this.isDataValid()
```

My IDE marked this with a warning

> Redundant 'await' for a non-promise type

So it seems my IDE is saying that `await` only needs to be used if an `async` function returns a promise i.e. there is no need to use `await` with `isDataValid` because it returns a boolean.

Does `await` need to be used when calling all `async` functions, or only those that return a promise?

### Update

I am using JavaScript, not TypeScript

Comment: Sure that `(await this.v$.$validate())` isnt't throwing the warning? This `const result = await this.isDataValid()` is totally correct as  `async` functions will always return a `Promise`.

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: Perhaps try adding a `;` so that you have `await this.isDataValid();`, the code after that line of code (which isn't shown in your question), might be accidentally chaining what you're awaiting. Otherwise, check that your IDE is up to date

Comment: Functions marked with the `async` keyword **ALWAYS** returns a promise. Your IDE is confused

Answer (score 1):

`await` is not necessary when using `async`.

Though if you are using async, it is inferred that your function returns a promise.

> The async is a function that is bound with a function that function returns the Promise object. The await operator holds the execution of the Promise function as long as the Promise is completely fulfilled.

As your function- `isDataValid` is not returning a promise in the first cycle, IDE marks the await as redundant.

The solution here is to return a promise from `isDataValid` function. Give the return type of `isDataValid` as `Promise<Boolean>` and make sure you in-real return a promise.

Comment: _ isDataValid is not returning a promise_ - that is incorrect. The function _is_ returning a promise. Every async function returns a promise, even if it's not explicitly stated in its body: `async function foo() { return 2 + 2; }` will return 4 wrapped in a promise.

Comment: @mbojko He mentioned in the first cycle.

Answer (score 1):

If you put await in front of a non promise, it will be auto wrapped in a promise and the value will be fulfilled (but in the next cycle). The execution order will definitely [change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55262996/does-awaiting-a-non-promise-have-any-detectable-effect).

> Does await need to be used when calling all async functions, or only those that return a promise?

You are going about it the wrong way. Do not think whether await needs to be used when calling all async functions, or only those that return a promise.

[`async`](https://javascript.info/async-await#async-functions) is only used when a function returns a promise. If you are using it for functions that do not return a promise, then you probably do not need it.

The async function returns a Promise. This promise will be resolved with the boolean value. `isValid` is a promise because even if it looks like a plain `Boolean`, notice that the value will only be evaluated once the `(await this.v$.$validate())` is fulfilled. So if you picture it in `.then` chaining mechanism, the value will be evaluated inside the `then` block and then the whole Promise will be resolved.

Something like this:

```
let isDataValid = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
this.v$.$validate().then((resolvedValidate) => {
  let isValid = resolvedValidate && externalValidation; 
  resolve(isValid);
});
});
```

In your case, I think the IDE is not able to figure out that `isValid` is actually going to be a `Promise<boolean>`. Either explicitly mark the return type like:

```
async isDataValid (externalValidation = true) : Promise<boolean> {
    const isValid = (await this.v$.$validate()) && externalValidation
    // other stuff not relevant to my question happens here
    return isValid
}
```

or ignore the warning.

Comment: Can I mark the return type as `: Promise<boolean>` in JavaScript, or this can only be used in TypeScript?

Comment: Only in TS buddy.

Comment: For plain JavaScript, there's still good old JSDoc. Declaring return type in the JSDoc could work.